# the argument scale of quoternion function "setRPY"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I want to use "setRPY"function and the arguments are the gyro sensor values.
I want to convert the angle to quotarnion by this function.

then , I have something I want to confirm.
Should I set the scale of the sensor value (angle) to [-2π , 2π]?
I don't know the scale of the function's argument .
please let me know the correct scale of the function.

My code is the following :

gyro_msg.vector.x = data.gx*PI()/180;
gyro_msg.vector.y = data.gy*PI()/180;
gyro_msg.vector.z = data.gz*PI()/180;
gyro_pub.publish(gyro_msg);

sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;
dt = (float) ( endTime - startTime ) * 0.000001; // μsec→sec

// integration

data.theta += dt * data.gz*PI()/180;

// range constraint

if(data.theta>=2*PI()) data.theta -=2*PI();
else if(data.theta<=2*PI()) data.theta +=2*PI();

imu_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
imu_msg.header.frame_id = "/base_link";
tf::Quaternion q;
q.setRPY(0.0, 0.0, data.theta);

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243488/the-argument-scale-of-quoternion-function-%22setrpy%22/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to my experience, I think the Roll Pitch Yaw range is (-π , π].

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2016-09-10**:
Thank you so much.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-11**:
@sasadasd: if you feel that @Shay has answered your question, please mark your question as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of this answer. Thanks.